# Neo4j Cypher query and composite objects

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a following Cypher query that returns all `Decision` that belong to a particular `Tag`:

```
MATCH (d:Decision)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(t:Tag) WHERE t.id = {tagId} RETURN d
```

According to my business logic every `Tag` can have a set of synonyms:

```
(t:Tag)<-[:FOR]-(ts:TagSynonym)-[:HAS]->(s:Tag)
```

and every `s:Tag` can also have a synonyms associated at the same way.. unlimited depth and where `ts.approved = true`.

Could you please show how to extend the first query in order to return not only Decisions associated with a start tag (`t.id = {tagId}`) but also the all Decisions associated with all tag's synonyms(unlimited depth).

Ideally all of these Decisions should be returned under one `d` variable.

Right now I'm playing with the following query:

```
MATCH p=(t:Tag)-[:FOR|HAS*]-(end:Tag) 
WHERE t.id = {tagId} AND NOT (end)<-[:FOR]-() 
OPTIONAL MATCH (d:Decision)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(tag) 
RETURN d
```

but it doesn't work.

**UPDATED**

I have created a Neo4j sandbox:

```
http://54.165.53.29:33761/browser/
neo4j
timer-rocks-hilltop
```

Please use the following query:

```
MATCH p=(t:Tag)-[:FOR|HAS*0..]-(end:Tag) 
WHERE t.id = 1 AND NOT (end)<-[:FOR]-() 
MATCH (d:Decision)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(end) 
RETURN d
```

It returns only the last Decision in the path(Decision3) but should also return Decision1 and Decision 2.

This is the [sample database](http://thedownloadplanet.com/data/default.graphdb.zip) username/password: neo4j/neo4j1

I have a 3 `Tag` and 3 `Decision` associated with this tag.

Also

`Tag 2` is a synonym of `Tag 1` and `Tag 3` is a synonym of `Tag 2`.

I need to find all of the `Decision` by `Tag 1` and by its synonyms(`Tag 2` and `Tag 3`). This is decisions: `Decision1`, `Decision2`, `Decision 3`

Comment: Can you plese post some sample of your data set and the expected result?

Comment: Sure, I have updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a subtle thing with variable depth traversals which is the zero depth :

```
MATCH p=(t:Tag)-[:FOR|HAS*0..]-(end:Tag) 
WHERE t.id = {tagId} AND NOT (end)<-[:FOR]-() 
MATCH (d:Decision)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(end) 
RETURN d
```

The idea is that, it handles both the cases where t nodes have a FOR or HAS relationships and when they not. The trick is that found tags (even the t node hence the 0) are under the `end` alias.

You can find a more in depth documentation about variable length relationships in this article : https://graphaware.com/graphaware/2015/05/19/neo4j-cypher-variable-length-relationships-by-example.html

**EDIT**

It seems the logic for finding the Tag nodes is wrong on your side, the query returns only one Tag due to this part in the query `AND NOT (end)<-[:FOR]-()`. Remove it and you'll see it returns 3 Decisions

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This query doesn't work as expected and returns only Decision 3 by Tag 1.. but according to my logic result should also contain Decision 1 and Decision 2

Comment: Right, well please share an online version of your graph then, at least we could test queries. There are plenty of tools, graphgen, sandbox, neo4j console etc.

Comment: I have provided a snapshot of my database at the question body. Honestly I have no idea how to import this data into sandbox

Comment: I have added sandbox